# How to avoid rerendering element in the array in react?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux-form

I have a array and I want to render the this array into a few redux forms. I found out that all the forms are rerendered. the code looks like the following:

Form.jsx

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import PropTypes from 'prop-types';
import { Link, Events, scrollSpy } from 'react-scroll';
import styles from './Form.css';
import MultipleForm from './MultipleForm';

class Form extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    const {
      workflows,
    } = this.props;
    this.state = {
      curTab: workflows.length > 0 ? workflows[0] : '',
      curForm: '',
    };
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    Events.scrollEvent.register('begin');
    Events.scrollEvent.register('end');
    scrollSpy.update();
  }
  componentWillReceiveProps(nextProps) {
    const {
      workflows,
    } = nextProps;
    if (workflows && workflows.length > this.props.workflows) {
      this.setState({
        curTab: workflows[0],
      });
    }
  }
  componentWillUnmount() {
    Events.scrollEvent.remove('begin');
    Events.scrollEvent.remove('end');
  }
  handleChangeTab = (value) => {
    this.setState({
      curTab: value,
    });
  }

  handleActiveTab = (workflow) => {
    console.log(workflow);
  }


  render() {
    const {
      workflows,
      schemaNames,
      ...rest
    } = this.props;
    return (
      <div className={styles.container}>
        <header>
          <PerspectiveBar
            value={this.state.curTab}
            onChange={this.handleChangeTab}
            style={{
              position: 'fixed',
              left: '0',
              top: '48px',
              width: '100vw',
              zIndex: '1380',
            }}
          >
            {workflows.map(wf => (
              <PerspectiveTab
                key={wf}
                label={wf}
                value={wf}
                onActive={() => this.handleActiveTab(wf)}
              />
          ))}
          </PerspectiveBar>
        </header>
        <div className={styles.formContainer}>
          <Paper className={styles.paperContainer}>
            <MultipleForm
              workflow={this.state.curTab}
              schemaNames={schemaNames}
              {...rest}
            />
          </Paper>
        </div>
        <Drawer className={styles.drawer} containerStyle={{ height: 'calc(100% - 104px)', top: '104px' }}>
          <div className={styles.drawerContainer}>
            {schemaNames.map(schemaName => (
              <Link
                onSetActive={(to) => {
                  this.setState({
                    curForm: to,
                  });
                }}
                to={schemaName}
                duration={500}
                offset={-104}
                spy
                smooth
              >
                <MenuItem
                  checked={this.state.curForm === schemaName}
                >
                  {schemaName}
                </MenuItem>
              </Link>
            ))}
          </div>
        </Drawer>
      </div>

    );
  }
}

Form.propTypes = {
  schemaNames: PropTypes.arrayOf(PropTypes.string),
  workflows: PropTypes.arrayOf(PropTypes.string),
  fetchSchemaNames: PropTypes.func.isRequired,
};

Form.defaultProps = {
  schemaNames: [],
  workflows: [],
};

export default Form;
```

MultipleForm.jsx

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import PropTypes from 'prop-types';
import FlatButton from 'material-ui/FlatButton';
import { Element } from 'react-scroll';
import SchemaForm from './SchemaForm';

class MultipleForm extends Component {
  componentDidMount() {
    console.log('MultipleForm Mounted');
    const {
      workflow,
      fetchSchemaNames,
    } = this.props;
    if (workflow) fetchSchemaNames(workflow);
  }

  componentWillReceiveProps(nextProps) {
    const {
      workflow,
      fetchSchemaNames,
    } = nextProps;
    if (workflow && this.props.workflow !== workflow) fetchSchemaNames(workflow);
  }

  componentDidUpdate() {
    const {
      schemaNames,
      schemas,
      initialValues,
      fetchSchemas,
      fetchInitialValues,
    } = this.props;
    const schemasNeedToFetch = this.remainingSchemas(schemaNames, schemas);
    if (schemasNeedToFetch.length !== 0) fetchSchemas(schemasNeedToFetch);
    const initialValuesNeedToFetch = this.remainingInitialValues(schemaNames, initialValues);
    if (initialValuesNeedToFetch.lenght !== 0) fetchInitialValues(initialValuesNeedToFetch, 1);
  }

  remainingSchemas = (schemaNames, schemas) =>
    schemaNames.filter(schemaName => schemaName in schemas === false).sort();

  remainingInitialValues = (schemaNames, initialValues) =>
    schemaNames.filter(schemaName => schemaName in initialValues === false).sort();

  handleSubmitAll = (event) => {
    event.preventDefault();
    const {
      submit,
      schemas,
      schemaNames,
    } = this.props;
    schemaNames
      .map(schemaName => schemas[schemaName].title)
      .forEach((title) => {
        submit(title);
      });
  }

  render() {
    const {
      schemaNames,
      schemas,
      initialValues,
      postForm,
    } = this.props;
    schemaNames.sort((a, b) => a.localeCompare(b));
    return (
      <div>
        {schemaNames.map(schemaName => (
          <Element name={schemaName}>
            <SchemaForm
              key={schemaName}
              schema={schemas[schemaName]}
              initialValue={initialValues[schemaName]}
              schemaName={schemaName}
              postForm={postForm}
            />
          </Element>
        ))}
        <div>
          <FlatButton
            label="Submit"
          />
          <FlatButton label="Deploy" />
        </div>
      </div>);
  }
}

MultipleForm.propTypes = {
  workflow: PropTypes.string.isRequired,
  submit: PropTypes.func.isRequired,
  fetchSchemaNames: PropTypes.func.isRequired,
  schemas: PropTypes.object,
  schemaNames: PropTypes.arrayOf(PropTypes.string),
  initialValues: PropTypes.object,
  fetchSchemas: PropTypes.func.isRequired,
  fetchInitialValues: PropTypes.func.isRequired,
  postForm: PropTypes.func.isRequired,
};

MultipleForm.defaultProps = {
  schemaNames: [],
};

export default MultipleForm;
```

SchemaForm

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import PropTypes from 'prop-types';
import Liform from 'liform-react';
import theme from './NokiaTheme';
import styles from './Form.css';

class SchemaForm extends Component {
  componentDidMount() {
    console.log('schema mounted');
  }

  shouldComponentUpdate() {
    return false;
  }
  handleSubmit = (value) => {
    const {
      postForm,
      schemaName,
    } = this.props;
    postForm(value, schemaName, 1);
  }


  render() {
    const {
      schema,
      initialValue,
    } = this.props;
    console.log('props', this.props);
    return (
      <div>
        <h3 id={schema.$id} className={styles.formTitle}>
          {schema.title}
        </h3>
        <Liform
          schema={schema}
          onSubmit={value => this.handleSubmit(value)}
          destroyOnUnmount={false}
          theme={theme}
          initialValues={initialValue}
        />
      </div>
    );
  }
}

SchemaForm.propTypes = {
  schema: PropTypes.shape({
    $id: PropTypes.string,
  }),
  initialValue: PropTypes.object,
  schemaName: PropTypes.string,
  postForm: PropTypes.func.isRequired,
};

SchemaForm.defaultProps = {
  schema: {},
  initialValue: null,
  schemaName: '',
};

export default SchemaForm;
```

the schemaNames will be changed only by adding or deleting some element. for example: the schemaNames will change from `['A', 'B', 'C']` to `['A', 'B', 'D']`.  I get the schemaNames from the redux. which I fetch online.

But when I check the ConnectedReduxForm, when I change the schemaNames, the SchemaForm will be unmounted and the react will mount the form again. I have tried with setting the ConnectedReduxForm to be PureComponent. It is not helpful.

Could someone help me with that? I have spent a lot of time of this and nothing helps.

**Update**: I have found the problem, the reason of it is that for each time that I for each time I update the workflow, I need to fetch the schemaNames from the server. But I still do not know why this happended. Could someone explain that?

Comment: Prehaps you need to apply the `key` to the DOM element that `ConnectedReduxForm` returns?

Comment: @Sidney Unfortunately, I have tried with that and it doesn't work.

Comment: sounds like `ConnectedReduxForm` just needs to implement [`shouldComponentUpdate`](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#shouldcomponentupdate)

Comment: @Hamms I have tried with set the shouldComponentUpdate function return false, and it doesn't work. Furthermore, the ConntectedReduxForm have been unmounted, I think there is nothing to do with the update.

Comment: @leuction If returning `false` from `shouldComponentUpdate` doesn't work, the re-render is likely being caused by a class decorator (probably Redux's `connect` decorator). You should post the source for `ConnectedReduxForm`.

Comment: @SimpleJ I just tried to directly import MyReduxForm instead connect the redux. shouldComponentUpdate doesn't work. it is quite wired.

Comment: Can you post your complete code somewhere? My feeling is that the parent component was unmounted and mounted again, but I can't be sure without trying the code myself.

Comment: @brickingup Hello, I have just uploaded all the code. But I think that the parent component has not been re-mounted.

Comment: `shouldComponentUpdate` should only return false if the component shouldn't update. It seems like you want the component to update only when its schemaName changes, so your `shouldComponentUpdate` method should reflect that

Comment: @Hamms I just return false for the test. The problem is I have no way to prevent the schemaForm to re-mount. All of three schemaForm are re-mounted. the multipleForm is not.

Comment: One thing I noticed is that in MultipleForm you put 'key' in SchemaForm while you should put it in Element. This may be the issue because each time MultipleForm re-renders Element will be re-mounted. So SchemaForm will also be re-mounted regardless of it's key.